# How to configure Spring to take a data from socket bytestream?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

I'm trying to configure `Spring` on the server side to open a socket, listen for connections and take the incoming stream (converting to `String`).

But I cannot find any working examples on how to just create such an incoming tcp connection. This is what I have (taken from an incomplete example):

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="cfServer"
    type="server"
    port="8080"
    using-nio="true"
    single-use="true" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundServer"
    channel="loop"
    connection-factory="server"/>

<int:channel id="loop"/>
```

Well, but how do I continue? How can I acutally bind these adapters to a backing class? And what do these classes have to look like?

Comment: Hi. Do you use any service activator (or any other consumer) that should get stream? Or you could not start any tcp server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribe something to the `loop` channel, e.g. a `<service-activator/>`.

See the [tcp-client-server sample](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server)